# I am getting an error in the following code

Tags: vba, excel

I want to refer to a array where last row is dynamic and its value is saved in a cell.

Can anyone help me whats wrong in this code

```
Sub Drop_down()
'
' Drop_down Macro
'

'
Sheets("Raw Data").Select
    Dim UC_count As Long

Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
UC_count = Worksheets("Raw Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    Sheets("Scoring Sheet").Select
    Range("B4").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(R3C&"":""&INDEX(RA_Sheet!R4C1:R &(UC_count+4)C20,MATCH('Scoring Sheet'!RC1,RA_Sheet!R4C1:R&(UC_count+4)C1,0),MATCH('Scoring Sheet'!R3C,RA_Sheet!R4C1:R4C20,0)),'PV Lookup Table'!R1C6:R108C9,4,0)"
```

Instead of UC_count if I write number then the code works well.

Comment: You should use a better title in the future. Stackoverflow is plenty of errors in other codes... this will help to find better responses. With all my respect: trying to help, only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
Range("B4").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(R3C&"":""&INDEX(RA_Sheet!R4C1:R" & (UC_count+4 ) & "C20,MATCH('Scoring Sheet'!RC1,RA_Sheet!R4C1:R" & (UC_count+4 ) & "C1,0),MATCH('Scoring Sheet'!R3C,RA_Sheet!R4C1:R4C20,0)),'PV Lookup Table'!R1C6:R108C9,4,0)"
```

It inserts the values of UC Count properly into the formula. (i didn't test the rest of the formula though).

Another tip; perhaps use a named range; and just update the named range when needed?